# How to Redirect registration page in wordpress

Tags: php, redirect, registration

my idea is, whenever someone visit my website he should be login or register to my website , I make custom login page and I redirect all page to that login page with the below code

```
function admin_redirect() {
if ( !is_user_logged_in()) {
   wp_redirect( home_url('/onboarding/') );
   exit;
}
}
add_action('get_header', 'admin_redirect');
```

can someone help to regirect all page to login page instead of registration page so people also can register to my website   , this is my website link https://wesh.site/en/

or give me code to strict user to login or register first , please with custom page

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I make a redirect in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/768431/how-do-i-make-a-redirect-in-php)

Comment: No sir it's not help me